# Receber entrada do usuário, usando Django Class Based Views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

> Caso seja necessário mais informações sobre o problema (urls.py, código completo do template, etc.) basta pedir que eu posto, só não coloquei pra não poluir muito o post.

**Descrição geral do problema:** Atualizar o gráfico criado em uma view de acordo com a entrada fornecida pelo usuário.

Eu tenho uma View do django que cria um gráfico com valores que eu defini na view.

Segue o código atual dela.

**views.py**

```
class ComecandoView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ComecandoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        lista_precos = []
        lista_datas = []
        for variacao in range(10500):
            lista_precos.append(rjson['dataset']['data'][variacao][4])
            lista_datas.append(rjson['dataset']['data'][variacao][0])
        # Create a trace
        trace = go.Scatter(
            y = lista_precos,
            x = lista_datas
        )
        data = [trace]
        fig = go.Figure(data=data)
        div = opy.plot(fig, auto_open=False, output_type='div')
        context['graph'] = div
        return context     
    template_name = 'comecando.html'
```

O que eu quero é que o usuário consiga selecionar (um valor de um combobox por exemplo) ou digitar em algum campo de texto um valor, o qual será retornado para a view dessa URL e lá um novo gráfico é gerado com esse novo valor e o template atualizado.

**Exemplo de funcionamento:** Um gráfico de cotações de 1980 até 2017 é gerado pela view por padrão. O usuário digita um valor num textfield na página e a página é recarregada, passando esse valor para a view e a mesma gera o gráfico novamente com as datas de 2000 até 2017 por exemplo.

**O que eu já tentei:**

**views.py**

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q')
        error = ''
        if not q:
            error = "error message"
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'error': error})
```

**comecando.html (template)**

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Dessa forma eu consigo acessar o valor do `input` dentro da função `get`, até consegui printar ele no terminal, mas o gráfico do `get_context_data` não é gerado.

Comment: Você já tentou capturar esse valor dentro do `get_context_data`?

Comment: @mazulo não, vou tentar aqui

Comment: @mazulo tentei, nao deu certo nao, o grafico ate foi gerado agora, mas a variavel `q` so fica disponivel dentro da funcao get e preciso usar ela pra gerar o novo grafico.

Comment: Talvez um teste seria chamar o `get_context_data` dentro do `get`, adicionar os novos valores e depois renderizar. Seria algo como:

`context = self.get_context_data()`
`context['q'] = request.GET.get('q')`